# POST request with python 400 Bad Request

Tags: javascript, python, api, post, request

In the online service javascript is using new Form Data to acquire an image and then passing through a simple api call retrieving an object with this code.

```
function sendSearchImage(form) {
console.log(">>> sendSearchImage");
var image = new FormData();
image.append('refImage', readFile);

$.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: instore_home + '/products/query',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: image,
        success: function (response) {
            console.log("<<< " + JSON.stringify(response));
            showQueryResults(response);
            //alert("Ref image successfully added: code " + response.refImgId);
            //alert(JSON.stringify(response));
            //window.location.reload();
        }
    });

return false;
}
```

I want instead to call the same API in python but i keep getting 400:Bad Request response, here it is my code up till now

```
 files = {'refImage': ('1.jpg', open(os.getcwd()+"/images/1.jpg", "rb"), 'image/jpeg')}
    headers = {"Content-Type":"multipart/form-data", "User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0"}
    r = requests.post('Url', headers=headers, data=files)
```

Could someone tell me in which format i should pass the data to obtain a good response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my doubt by not specifying the header, it seems that is built automatically and with the manual implementation you risk to not be able to get all the value right since some of them is even dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably the user agent you use to access the webpage. Use this header in your headers variable instead:

```
headers = {"Content-Type":"multipart/form-data","User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0"}
```

Comment: I've tried to do as suggested but nothing changed, i changed a bit the post format to be as similar as possible to the http body request but i actually don't have documentation for that